# Komodo Cucumber String Highliting

Tags: syntax, cucumber, highlighting

When writing a scenario in Cucumber using Komodo Edit, is it possible to use a single quote without Komodo interpreting it as a string syntax?

Example:

Scenario: The man's laptop turns on

The standard Cucumber syntax highlighting will highlight everything after the single quote until the next single quote or end of file as a giant string.  Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to figure out a way of doing this without making code changes to the plugin.

I created a [fork](https://github.com/mithat/cucumber_language) of ccaroon's [original](https://github.com/ccaroon/cucumber_language) repo that disables single-quote strings altogether. This solves the problem for me.

You will have to build the extension per the `README.md`. On Linux you can find `koext` in `<komodo-install-dir>/lib/sdk/bin/`. It's likely similar on other platforms.